# Get string containing email addresses split by one or more commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to split a specific string by a single comma containing email addresses.
The string can be complicated like `"abc@xyz.com,xyz@xyz.com,,,pqr@xyz.com,,,,123@xyz.com,"`

And preferred output is as follows `"abc@xyz.com,xyz@xyz.com,pqr@xyz.com,123@xyz.com"`

I tried using jQuery `split()` but cannot find a proper way of doing this

Comment: The jQuery split method?

Comment: What you're looking for is `str.replace(/,+/g, ",")`

Comment: You can use Plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Email-Address-Management-Multiple-Emails.html

Comment: Why not replace `,,` with `,` until there are no more `,,` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var str = "abc@xyz.com,xyz@xyz.com,,,pqr@xyz.com,,,,123@xyz.com,"
str = str.split(',');
str = str.filter(function(v){return v!==''}).join(',');
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = "abc@xyz.com,xyz@xyz.com,,,pqr@xyz.com,,,,123@xyz.com,"
str = str.split(',');
str = str.filter(function(v){return v!==''}).join(',');
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for the moment but there is a better way :D

```
var str =  "abc@xyz.com,xyz@xyz.com,,,pqr@xyz.com,,,,123@xyz.com,";
str = str.split(',').filter(a => a).join(',');
console.log(str);
```

the following looks definitely better to me:

```
str = str.replace(/,+/g, ",").replace(/,(.*),/, '$1');
```